# how to perform an action repeatedly when a Gesture Detector is held down Flutter

Tags: flutter, for-loop, tetris

I have programmed the Tetris game in flutter but I am having some problems with the Gesture Detector.
I wish that when the button that brings the blocks down is held down it causes the block to go down very quickly, so I would like when a Gesture Detector is held down this command was repeated quickly:

```
keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(move: const Offset(0, sizePerSquare));
```

This is the affected part of the code:

```
class _TetrisGamePageState extends State<TetrisGamePage> {

  GlobalKey<_TetrisWidgetState> keyGlobal = GlobalKey();
  ValueNotifier<List<BrickObjectPos>> brickObjectPosValue =
      ValueNotifier<List<BrickObjectPos>>(List<BrickObjectPos>.from([]));
  ValueNotifier<Scoring> scoring = ValueNotifier<Scoring>(Scoring());
  bool endLoop = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double sizePerSquare = 25;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
              color.AppColorMode.firstColor,
              color.AppColorMode.secondColor
            ])),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SafeArea(child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              ValueListenableBuilder(
                                  valueListenable: scoring,
                                  builder: (context, Scoring value, child) {
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Scores: ${value.score}', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 6),
                                        Text('Multipler: ${value.multipler}x', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }
                                  ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    keyGlobal.currentState!.resetGame();
                                  },
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                              (states) => Colors.blue)),
                                  child: const Text('Start',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    keyGlobal.currentState!.pauseGame();
                                  },
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                              (states) => Colors.blue)),
                                  child: const Text('Pause',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Next: ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          ValueListenableBuilder(
                              valueListenable: brickObjectPosValue,
                              builder:
                                  (context, List<BrickObjectPos> value, child) {
                                BrickShapeEnum tempShapeEnum = value.isNotEmpty
                                    ? value.last.shapeEnum
                                    : BrickShapeEnum.line;
                                int rotation =
                                    value.isNotEmpty ? value.last.rotation : 0;
                                return BrickShape(
                                    BrickShapeStatic.getListBrickOnEnum(
                                        tempShapeEnum,
                                        direction: rotation));
                              })
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 300,
                height: 400,
                child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                  return TetrisWidget(
                      constraints.biggest,
                      key: keyGlobal,
                      sizePerSquare: sizePerSquare,
                      setCallbackScore: (Scoring score) {
                        scoring.value = score;
                        scoring.notifyListeners();
                      },
                      setNextBrick: (List<BrickObjectPos> brickObjectPos) {
                        brickObjectPosValue.value = brickObjectPos;
                        brickObjectPosValue.notifyListeners();
                      });
                }),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(move: const Offset(-sizePerSquare, 0)),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13))
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft)
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onLongPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        endLoop = false;
                      });
                      while(endLoop == false) {
                        keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(move: const Offset(0, sizePerSquare));
                      }
                    },
                    onLongPressUp: () {
                      setState(() {
                        endLoop = true;
                      });
                    },
                    onTap: () => keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(move: const Offset(0, sizePerSquare)),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13))
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowDown)
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(rotate: true),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 45,
                      height: 45,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13))
                      ),
                      child: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.rotate),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => keyGlobal.currentState!.transformBrick(move: const Offset(sizePerSquare, 0)),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13))
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowRight)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        })),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see all my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/FabioTambu/tempRepo)

Comment: And how does your current attempt fail?

Comment: On the terminal it doesn't give me any errors, but the block simply stops descending completely, it remains stationary in the air

Comment: I would like my loop to start when the GestureDetector is held down and stop when it is released